# Check two conditions in two different columns, to pull amount in third column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

```
**TYPE** | **New** | **Amount**
MM       |   YES   |  $25.00
DDA      |   YES   |  $0.00
MM       |    NO   |  $0.00
MM       |   YES   |  $25.00
```

Basically, I want to get the total amount ($50.00) if the type is MM and New = YES.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C5, B2:B5, "YES", A2:A5, "MM")
```

> Summary of function from Microsoft: **Adds the cells in a range that meet multiple criteria.**
>
> **`C2:C5`** is the column that needs to be summed if the requirements are met.
>
> **`B2:B5`** is the column with your `YES` and `NO` values to check. If `YES` then first check passes
>
> **`A2:A5`** is your other string value to check. If `MM` then second check passes.
>
> If both checks pass then sum the respective values from cell range (`C2:C5`)

In the data ranges, do not include the header.

This gives the result 50 that you were after in your example.

Make sure that the column with the prices is formatted as currency.

Source: [SUMIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Comment: @user351000 Please accept the answer by checking the green tick if you find this method useful :)

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1**

You can use `IF` and `AND` to achieve your desired results.  In cell D2 type

```
=IF(AND(A2="MM", B2="YES"),C2,0)
```

When the two conditions inside `AND(...)` are met, `AND(...)` becomes true, and the `IF(...)` will have the value of the second parameter i.e. `C2`.  Otherwise `IF(...)` returns the third parameter i.e. `0`.

**Method 2**

```
=C2*(A2="MM")*(B2="YES")
```

`(A2="MM")` evaluates to 1 if it holds, otherwise it is 0.  If both conditions are met, the formula becomes `C2*1*1` which is C2.  Otherwise, it could be, say `C2*1*0` which is 0 if the second column is not "YES".